# Is there a way to ensure that my computer will require password after some minutes?

Tags: windows-10

I don't want my computer to switch or log off or hibernate. There are programs still running.

However, I want my windows 10 to effectively "try to switch" user after a certain minutes.

That way, I can leave my computers knowing that everything there is save after a few minutes.

Comment: Why not use a [password protected screen saver](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000790.htm)?

Comment: Have you tried creating a scheduled task?

Comment: David Postill. That is the right answer. Please turn that into an answer.